# Create a Stream of Bytes

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

In Java 8, I am finding this a bit odd. I can't seem to create a byte stream out of a `byte[]` array. The `Array.stream` class seems to only work on `int[]`, `long[]`, `double[]`, or `T[]`.

```
public long update(final byte[] buffer) {
    crc = 0L;
    Arrays.stream(buffer).forEach(this::update); // expecting to go into a function update(byte b)
    return crc;
}
```

When I try alternatives like `Stream.of(buffer)` or `Arrays.asList(buffer).stream().forEach(this::update);` the stream just reflects itself and I get a `byte[]`.

Am I missing something in the implementation here?

Comment: You would need to use `Array.stream()` if it existed.  Byte streams were considered a corner case during the development of Java's stream API and not implemented.  The assumption was that int streams would be good enough.

Comment: Hmm you'd think there would be an internal way to handle byte[] as if it were int[] internally? I.e., under the hood, could they have an Array.stream which converted the byte[] to int[]?

Comment: For byte processing, the established practice is to use IO streams or NIO channels for which there's considerable amount of tooling in libraries like Commons or Guava (even if no actual IO takes place and all operations are done on buffers/byte arrays). That's probably the main underlying reason why bytes where omitted from the "functional" stream API.